# Kubernetes Dashboard by Request ID - Distributed Tracing (for AWS EKS using Istio Service Mesh)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, dashboard

I have several applications deployed on AWS EKS as microservices.

They are also deployed across different AWS accounts and have dependencies on each other.

I would like some kind of dashboard that says where exactly a request failed in a long flow of request across say 10 different microservices (m1 calls m2 and so on till m5 and say 1 request fails at m2 and another at m4, i would like to see a dashboard that shows where this flow got interrupted for each request).

How could I achieve to get this dashboard?

FOund this tool named ZIkpin which provides pretty much what I am looking for.

[image]

Any alternatives available? DOes ELK provide this dashboard? How about Kiali?

I am using istio for service mesh. Is any dashboard available that works best with istio for distributed tracing?

Answer (score 1):

To cover the scenario you mention here, firstly make sure to have a centralized logging. I have used Elk and found it to be good covering logs from multiple services and it comes with a good dashboard view to debug the logs.

You can have different source types for logs across the micro services to differentiate while debugging. use something like a request-id which flows across all the 10 different services which the request hits in the path. This would make the identification easier, there are other ways too to handle it but for someone new to the flow could debug faster

You can use filebeat to push the logs with different log levels to elk from the log files generated at every ms.

Kibana dashboard is good for monitoring and comes with multiple search options as basic as http status code 500 which would directly give all internal server errors.

To improve further monitoring use alerts, graphs to get triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I found this tool named Zipkin which shows distributed tracing diagrams. I feel that is precisely what I am looking for.<img src="https://zipkin.io/public/img/web-screenshot.png" alt="Trace view screenshot"/>